# test facebook with friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a big problem. I would like to do a facebook app that, when I click the button "Begin test", search on my friends list. For example I would like to create a test called "What's your best friend?" and when I click on the button it give me the name of a random friend of mine. I really don't know how to do it, I searched on differents sites but I still have no answers. Here you are an example: http://it.nametests.com/test/chi-delle-tue-amiche-e-la-tua-fata-turchina/6382/

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, please get familiar with graph API and the process of getting access to friendlist using access tokens of users. Afterwards, once you are able to get infomation about friends, you can write a function to get a random name from the list. More information on developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible anymore, you can only get access to friends who authorized your App too. More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

The API call would be `/me/friends`.

Btw, i would consider those Apps "Spam Apps" - you don´t REALLY get your "best friend", you just get a random one. There´s no logic behind it. You should not create even more of those Spam Apps.

Also, Stackoverflow is a platform for developers, you should always do some research/testing/programming/debugging before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: But if it's not possible anymore, why the app in the example still running?

Comment: what exactly does the app do? i don't want to authorize it, those apps are often malicious. it is possible that they are using taggable_friends or invitable_friends - which would not be allowed if you don't want to tag or invite users.

Comment: The app, when you click the button, pick a random friends of your friends list of facebook. Then the selected friend has shown as "your fairy friend"

Comment: classic spam app then. either way, most likely using an api endpoint that is not allowed for the case.